# Draw a parallel bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curve

This may be a duplicate of [Control points of offset bezier curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465782/control-points-of-offset-bezier-curve) but I am not quite able to say so. Also, the answers linked there are just one level more abstract than is helpful to my limited understanding.

I have a bezier curve. 
I want to give an offset distance. I would then like to know, given the vertices and control points in the given curve, at what positions should the vertices and control points be in the second, offset curve?

I think that my curve is relatively simple, at its most complex it would approximate an inchworm: start out flat, curve up then back down, and then flat again (left to right).

I am using [Processing](http://processing.org/reference/) (vertex() and bezierVertex()) in case that's helpful.

Comment: My answer there still applies: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/465789/589.

Comment: So does mine. The Tiller-Hanson algorithm should be easy enough to understand -- all you have to do is offset the control polygon.