# Offset Approximate The Cubic Bezier

Tags: computational-geometry, bezier-curve

Given a cubic Bezier curve $B_3(t)$, and the offset radius $d$, we know the exact $d$-offset curve is 
$$X_d(t):=B_3(t)+d\cdot N(t),$$
where $N(t)$ denotes the normal direction to the $B_3(t)$.

**Q**: Are there some good method to approximate the $X_d$ by the Cubic Bezier curve?

*PS*: I just knew the Hoschek-method [Slide of the Hoschek Method](http://www-hagen.cs.uni-kl.de/~gm/pdf/14/gm_14_09.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

See the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465782/control-points-of-offset-bezier-curve/467038#467038).

The notes by Hagen that you linked to are rather narrow in their focus, in my opinion. There are many different approaches to the offsetting problem, and he covers only a few of them.