# Creating a curve at a fixed distance from a cubic Bezier curve

Tags: calculus, bezier-curve

Let $P(t)$ be a cubic Bezier curve. I want to create a second curve $P_r(t)$, in which each point is a fixed distance $r$ from a point in $P$.

In other words, add the vector of magnitude $r$ that is perpendicular to the tangent of each point in $P(t)$, and call the result $P_r(t)$. Something like:

$$P_r(t) = P(t) + r\frac{P'(t)^\perp}{|P'(t)|}$$

To describe the problem visually, consider the following image:

[A cubic Bezier curve w/ outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYF8N.png)

The curve I am describing can be seen as either edge of the shaded region (top or bottom, depending on whether $r$ is positive or negative).

My question is:

- Can this curve also be described as a cubic Bezier curve?
- If so, how can its control points be computed?

Comment: It will not, by far, be a cubic Bezier curve. Locally it will be algebraic with degree maybe 10 or 12 (instead of 3)...Important : Try googling with keywords "offset curve" or "parallel curve" coupled with "bezier" of course

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465782/control-points-of-offset-bezier-curve

Comment: The curve you seek is called an "offset" curve in CAD, and a "parallel" curve in traditional differential geometry. If you search this site (or elsewhere) for the terms "offset" and "Bezier", you will find quite a bit of material, which will probably meet your needs.