# Calculating the two outer Bezier Curves of a thick Bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curve

I'm creating a Bezier curve using 4 control points (left photo). If the same curve was 100px thick (right photo) is it possible to calculate the control points needed to create the 2 red curves using the original points? Where can I learn more about this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: When adding the width you need a normalized normal vector which doesnt have a polynomial form, so the boundary curves are not beziers. The normalization also has a square root, so it aint a nurbs either.

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465782/control-points-of-offset-bezier-curve.

Comment: Or search for “offset curve” on this site or elsewhere.